# Playwright parallel execution skips tests

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, playwright

I am currently implementing tests for a system accessible via rest. The tests are programmatically created to check access rights for different users and endpoints in the target system.
The code creating the tests looks something like this:

```
test.describe('Access tests', () => {
  test.beforeAll(async ({request}) => {
    // Create system Data
  })
  test.afterAll(async ({request}) => {
    // Delete system Data
  })

  users.forEach((user) => {
    test.describe(`${user}`, () => {
      test.beforeAll(async ({request}) => {
        // Create user data
      })
      test.afterAll(async ({request}) => {
        // Delete user data
      })

      endpoints.forEach((endpoint) => {
        test(`${endpoint.name}`, async ({request}) => {
          // assert actual access with expected access
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

These tests run as expected when run in sequential mode (all the tests are in one file, so the default configuration).
The problem is that when I switch to `defineConfig({fullyParallel: true})` and increase the number of workers, about *half of the tests are skipped*. Why is that the case, and how could I increase the test runtime without skipping tests?

I tried different amounts of workers, leading to the same result of skipped tests. An increased amount of workers also did not decrease the execution time above two workers. The only way all tests run is in sequential mode.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code - works well.

```
import { test } from "@playwright/test";

test.describe("Access tests", () => {
  test.beforeAll(async ({ request }) => {
    console.log("Before all tests");
    await request.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=beforeAll`);
  });
  test.afterAll(async ({ request }) => {
    console.log("After all tests");
    await request.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=afterAll`);
  });

  const users = ["admin", "merchant", "customer"];

  users.forEach((user) => {
    test.describe(`${user}`, () => {
      test.beforeAll(async ({ request }) => {
        console.log(`Create ${user}`);
        await request.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=create${user}`);
      });
      test.afterAll(async ({ request }) => {
        console.log(`Delete ${user}`);
        await request.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=delete${user}`);
      });

      const endpoints = ["endpoint1", "endpoint2", "endpoint3", "endpoint4", "endpoint5", "endpoint6"];
      endpoints.forEach((endpoint) => {
        test(`${endpoint}`, async ({ request }) => {
          console.log(`Test ${endpoint} for ${user}`);
          await request.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${endpoint}`);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

with config

```
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from "@playwright/test";

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  fullyParallel: true,
  workers: 20,
  // ...
}
```

None of them skipped - each test has own

```
Before all tests
Create admin
Test endpoint1 for admin
Delete admin
After all tests
```

As an alternative - try to replace forEach with for loop

```
for (const user of users) {
```

instead of

```
users.forEach((user) => {
```

Also, try to debug it with traces, https://trace.playwright.dev/, to see why it's been skipped.